# C# Help parsing xml

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

Good day everyone. I've been trying to get the attributes of a specific XML node but I'm failing. I'm using *System.Xml*.

**Here's the XML code:**

```
<report type="Full" sr="28">
    ...
</report>
```

I'm trying to get the *type* and *sr* attributes.

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load("test.xml");

XmlNodeList reportNodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("report");
XmlAttributeCollection reportNodeAttributeCollection = reportNodeList.Item(0).Attributes;
string reportType = reportNodeAttributeCollection.GetNamedItem("type").ToString(); //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
string sr = reportNodeAttributeCollection.GetNamedItem("sr").ToString();
```

I didn't expect it to work and it didn't. I have some experience with parsing XML but only the very basics of it. Could someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain how exactly it "didn't work".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to use *Value* instead of *ToString*:

```
string reportType = reportNodeAttributeCollection.GetNamedItem("type").Value;
string sr = reportNodeAttributeCollection.GetNamedItem("sr").Value;
```

Comment: The initial problem was that I was getting the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. I realized that the _sr_ attribute didn't exist in the _test.xml_ file, my bad. However, this solves the second problem where _ToString()_ was giving me the name of the type (_XmlAttribute_) instead of the value of the attribute.

Comment: Also, I want to ask: Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have to get the attributes of a few other nodes and doing the same thing for all of them will create a huge mess..

Comment: One other way is to use _xpath_ ... e.g, string reportType = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("report/@type").Value;